# How to add a new ClusterRoleBinding with Kustomize in k8s without removing existing bindings?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

When I type `kubectl edit clusterrolebinding foo-role`, I can see something like:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: foo-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: foo-user
  namespace: ns1
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: foo-user
  namespace: ns2
```

I can add a new `ClusterRoleBinding` for namespace `ns3` by appending the following config to above file:

```yaml
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: foo-user
  namespace: ns3
```

However, I want to use Kustomize to add new bindings instead of manually modifying the above file.

I tried to apply the .yaml file below:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: foo-role
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/foo-role
  uid: 64a4a787-d5ab-4c83-be2b-476c1bcb6c96
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: foo-user
  namespace: ns3
```

It did add a new `ClusterRoleBinding` in the namespace `ns3`, but it will remove existing `ClusterRoleBinding`s for `ns1` and `ns2`.

Is there a way to add new `ClusterRoleBinding` with Kustomize without removing existing ones?

Comment: Did below coderanger answer fixed your issue or it's something else?

Comment: No, it didn't. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them different names in the metadata. You didn't make a new one, you just overwrote the same one.

Comment: No, I don't want to give them different names. I just want to bind `foo-user` in `ns3` to `foo-role`.

Comment: Then list all the subjects at the same time. The object you see is the object you get. It's not like an RPC call, these are REST objects.

Comment: (you will have to use an rfc6902 patch for this)

Comment: If I use rfc6902 patch, will I be able to only list the subjects I want to add?

Comment: Sure, I guess. Why not make multiple objects though? That's how this is supposed to work. You can have as many bindings as you want.

Comment: Because it requires 3 steps: retrieving the latest subject list, modify the subject list, send out the subject list. I don't know how to do the first step in Kustomize automatically.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how kustomize works. It can’t retrieve anything.

Comment: After some testings, I found out that I should have use a different name in the metadata. I'll accept your answer. Thank you so much.